# Umbraco Visual Studio solution (v4.7)

Tags: visual-studio, umbraco

I am using the Jupiter as Visual Studio solution project for a v5 umbraco site -

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/jupiter-as-visual-studio-solution

however i'm struggling to find the project to use for v4.x Does anyone know if it can be accessed anywhere or if i can easily recreate?

Answer (score 1):

You can still access the Umbraco 4.7.1.1 downloads [here](http://umbraco.codeplex.com/releases/view/73692).

If you don't want/need the full blown source, you may just want to run the 'webdeploy' option as a website in Visual Studio.